# Transfer Image from centralized database to remote android application

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I am new in Android Development. My simple question :- i want to create an e-commerce android app . I want to make it dynamic ie if a new product is added to already created JSP site or particularly Mysql database , how can i sent information including image file from mysql database to android app? I know little bit about Http request response in android, as well as jason array but was only able to send text. How to achieve same for images?

Answer (score 0):

use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html to show your server-generated html-page.

Comment: i dont want to a web page in activity.

Comment: webview is the easiest option for your case. Imagine, if you have to send 2 or more images? How do you want position them? If you stick to not using the WebView, then you have to build the whole mechanism on your own. In that case your will have to use `sockets`. There is lots of info on that topic here on SOF

Answer (score 0):

send text only - send the URL to the image and the app can then download it

Comment: none that I am aware of. We have a shopping cart app - we get JSON text from our server, which includes paths/URLs for image. Our app simply downloads the images before setting any ImageView. Its really not a big deal